# display:inline-block and display:inline Property Clarification Do what to use

Tags: html, css

As I am trying to move that subscribe button to be little more up which should be in the centre of the text at left side.

If I use `display:inline` I can able to achieve that what I am expecting for

but same thing I want to achieve it in `display:inline-block`

and also I used

> **width:400px**

for the

> **.panel3 #cont**

If I zoom in the browser the text are not wrapping inside the width:400px, I need it to be responsive of text should be break down automatically inside the div when it is zoomed also.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/gbgB4/10/

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel3">
<div id="wrap" style="padding:0.4in">
<div id="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</div>
<div id="cont" align="left">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel3 {
    width:100%;
    min-height:120px;
    background-color: #233247;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    color: white;
}
.panel3 div div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.panel3 #cont {
    font-size: 21px;
    width:400px;
    min-width:100px;
    text-align: left;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.panel3 #button input[type="submit"] {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    min-height: 45px;
    width: 200px;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#233247;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: `padding:0.4in` for first time I saw 'inch' in use #frankly

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/gbgB4/7/

Comment: #frankly for the first time I saw a hashtag in SO comments

Comment: Thanks for your comment jonas see this fiddle now
http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/gbgB4/12/

Answer (score 0):

Give

```
  .panel3 #button { margin-right:30px; }
```

And Remove Padding from the,

```
 .panel3 #cont { padding:0px; }
```

Working Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/gbgB4/5/

Also you have to add media query for mobile to achieve this,

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
 .panel3 #cont { display:inline-block; }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment husen but see jsfiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/3/, disply:inline-block

if this was the case?? then what should i do

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/gbgB4/12/ want to be like this but button should be middle of the right paragraph two lines

Comment: I have posted both the case: Case 1 : normal mode without Zoom : http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/gbgB4/25/ and Case 2 : Zoom mode : http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/gbgB4/24/

Comment: But in your case the text is falling down the subscribe button, but i need the next line to be fall down below the 1st line starting properly indent after the subscribe button

Comment: Husen please reply me brother